# Why does vars(type('', (object,), input_dict)()) not return its variables?

Tags: python-3.x, class, object

To convert dict to class, I wrote the code as follows, and it works well.

```
output_class = type('', (object,), input_dict)()
```

However, the created class does not return its attributes by the code below!

```
print(vars(output_class))
>> {}
```

I solved this problem by using the code below, but I am still confused.

```
class Struct(object):
    def __init__(self, **entries):
      self.__dict__.update(entries)
output_class = Struct(**input_dict)

print(vars(output_class))
>> {'key': 'value'}
```

I would appreciate it if you could explain why the former does not return its attributes.

Answer (score 0):

It's because in first case (calling type) object of your class has an empty `__dict__` and your input_dict content is stored in class variables.
third argument of `type()` defines class (not object) variables or methods (they are defined by `__new__` call not `__init__` ).

Simply put, the first and the second code snippets are not the same.

So

`output_class = type('', (object,), input_dict)()`,

Has equivalent something like this:

```
class Struct(object):
    def __new__(cls, **entries):
      cls = super().__new__()
      for k,v in **entries:
          setattr(cls, k, v)
      return obj
output_class = Struct()
```

If you want something like:

```
class Struct(object):
    def __init__(self, **entries):
      self.__dict__.update(entries)
output_class = Struct(**input_dict)
```

You should define **init**(). It can look like:

```
output_class = type('', (object,), 
{'__init__': lambda self, inp_d: self.__dict__.update(inp_d)})(input_dict)
```

If my explanation isn't enough clear I suppose example from here can help: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type
Pay you attention: a is not inside `__init__()` method so it's shared between all objects of class X.